# More realistic currency for spaceship battle game

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

This is slightly related to real development but as you know hardest thing to do for developer is naming things. So now I can't figure out what specific currency to use in my spaceship battle game.

**Little about game**: Space, universe, spaceships, battles. Ships can be destroyed, damaged, repaired, aliens (multi-race) - typical spaceship game. Multiplayer, turn-based, battles not limited to 1 vs 1 - can be different count in both teams (70 vs 45).

Struggle is I want more realistic currency than just `credits`, `gold`, `crystals` etc. Because game currency should be related to battles, repair etc. And maybe (but not mandatory for now) with context to other alien races.

All options is viewed from game character perspective not player.

### Requirements:

- Something to get after battle (*imagine destroyed ship, what to salvage*)
- Used to repair ship (*can be as part of some kind of tool*)
- Valuable stuff to give someone in distinct part of universe
- Space pirates would want to have this stuff

#### 1. `Credits` (EVE, Elite:Dangerous)

*Fictional*. No context to game universe at all.

#### 2. `Crystals` or other minerals (majority of games?)

*Game related, fictional value*.

This works but if we think in scope of Universe as whole for some aliens this mineral could be worth nothing.

#### 3. `Scrap metal` (FTL)

*Game related , real value*.

Best option for now is `scrap`, `scrap metal` as you know "FTL" game is using. This works only if we assume all ships in all universe using metal for building spaceships.

It can be used as repair material, it can be found after battle even if ship is empty.

Kinda feel bad to *steal* this currency from FTL as I love that game :)

#### 4. exotic currencies

Using these would be interesting but need

- `time` - Works great with repairing stuff
- `information` - Great currency to salvage after battle from another ship, but fails to for repairing ship.
- more?

### Summary

I know there is quite obvious answer but wanted to reach to others and maybe hear something I never though of.

Maybe you can write your pros and cons about every currency i mentioned or point out something where to look?

Comment: Is your game single player or multiplayer?

Comment: Multiplayer and with bots. *Updated main post with more description about game*.

Comment: I would suggest you read [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Virtual-Economies-Design-Analysis-Information/dp/0262027259) to help you get started. A multiplayer game economy is no small task to do right.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is on topic here, though (a bit too 'discussion oriented' IMHO). You might want to flag your question (moderator intervention) to have it moved to [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: thanks for your time and directions. Agree this was not truly related to "dev".

Comment: Game design questions are very much welcome, but it's a bit of a grey zone when the topic is more discussion oriented, from what I have noticed.

Comment: In the real world, space ships need two things: mass and energy.  Energy is used to power the ship, for pretty much everything.  Mass is used to make the ship (usually metal, for a large number of reasons).  Mass is also used to _move_ the ship (reaction mass - throw something out the other direction), which can be **water** (most comets have some water component).  Water has several other uses, too, including radiation shielding and armor (in solid form).  How hard

Comment: check our worldbuilding.SE: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/9064/858 (@AlexandreVaillancourt it's a dupe to this one)

Comment: @ratchetfreak that's a good one.

Comment: I see a couple options for you: 1) don't set any currency. One will end up emerging, players will figure that out by trading stuff (this might not be practical when trading with NPCs, and balancing the faucet of goods will be hard.) 2) have one currency per race (nation); e.g. Gold for Humans, Kryptonite for Supermanians and Self-sealing stem bolts for Lissepians. This would help create a dynamic economy. Currencies are good enablers for trades, so trading with base currency makes sense. And you could eventually control the exchange rates for these to improve balance.

Comment: I read some discussions from Worldbuilding too and looks like I'm going for currency per race. At least for now. Maybe it will be energy source(crystals) or scrap metal (for ship building/repairing) it matters little bit less if every race would have different valuables. And (when I actually bring it to game multiple races) they interact with each other they can salvage different currencies from destroyed ship and choose where to trade them.

Thanks for help @AlexandreVaillancourt , maybe something will change but at least I'm not in the dead end! :)